# jQuery returns text but function does change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

**As you can see in the image it says +$10.00 (shown in red below)- this bit is what i am trying to remove.**

[image: Example of price increase]

The indigo colored area is: `<dt class="swatch-attr">`

The red colored ares is: `<span class="select-label">`

The swatch buttons are wrapped in: `<span class="swatch-label">`

I have unsuccessfully tried to remove this using this bit of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
        checkswatches();

        jQuery("span.swatch-label").click(function(){
            checkswatches();
        });
    });

    function checkswatches(){
      jQuery("span.select-label").each(function(){
        var optiontext = jQuery(this).text();
        var addsignpos = optiontext.indexOf('+');
        var subtractsignpos = optiontext.indexOf('-');
        if(addsignpos>0){
            var result = optiontext.substring(0,addsignpos-1);
            jQuery(this).html(result);
        }

        if(subtractsignpos>0){
            var result = optiontext.substring(0,subtractsignpos-1);
            jQuery(this).html(result);
        }
      });
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

**When I run the function above the price increase exhibited in the image above is still shown.**

[Live Example](http://wesoldistribution.com/mage/index.php/mens-accessories/shirt-lock.html)

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does the line `var optiontext = jQuery(this).text();` work?

Comment: `checkswatches` doesn't have a `return` statement. Not sure what you expect the function to return... you are not even doing anything with the return value of the function. Or are you talking about a different function? `jQuery("swatch-label")` uses the wrong selector btw.

Comment: What do you mean by *when the function runs it returns `undefined`"*? What *function*? Bear in mind `.text()` never returns `undefined`. When you run `jQuery("span.select-label").text()` alone, it returns the text for the first matched element only. When run inside `.each()` it will get the text for each of the elements (the first one will be the same as `jQuery("span.select-label").text()`, but the rest won't).

Comment: Does your link `jQuery("span.select-label")` run before the text is changed by another method? Reason you do not just remove the "+" in that code?

Comment: @AWood Do you expect `checkswatches` function to return something else? There is no `return` statement.

Comment: I should clarify i meanby return is console returns undefined when the function runs. When `jQuery("span.select-label").text();` it returns the correct text.

Comment: @FelixKling why is this the wrong selector?

Comment: It will look for elements with **tag name** `swatch-label` (i.e. `<swatch-label>`, not for elements with such a **CSS class** (which would be `jQuery(".swatch-label")`).

Comment: @acdcjunior There is only one element on the page under `span.select-label`.

Comment: @epascarello yes it does but it then also runs again when the swatch button is clicked.

Comment: @AWood The console shows `undefined` because the function has no `return` statement. `undefined` is the default return value of a function.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for pointing this out - i didnt realize. I just need the price to not be shown on the page.

Comment: The price isn't in the `select-label` span.

Comment: The price is in `<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-14">
                                            <span class="price">$14.95</span>                                    </span>`

Comment: Oh, I see, clicking on the size button fills in `select-label`.

Comment: @Barmar i am talking about the price incrase shown in red in the image above or `<span class="select-label" id="select_label_wd_size">`

Comment: The function is working. If you step through it in the debugger, you see the price disappear. Then it gets added back by something that reacts to hovering over the button.

Comment: @AWood Do you want to remove the price from this element for the whole website? You'd be better off tracking down and editing the bit of code that adds it in the first place. The function `getOptionLabel(option,price)` in http://wesoldistribution.com/mage/js/varien/configurable.js appears to be it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function checkswatches(){
    jQuery("span.select-label").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).text(
          jQuery(this).text().replace(/[+-]\$[0-9\.]+/g, "")
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this does not work. When embeded in the page noting happens. When run in the console it returns undefined.

Comment: @AWood Why do you still expect it to return something when there's no `return` statement? Why does the return value matter, the function is just being used to modify the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar sorry i was confused about the returning in the console. This code however, does not change the text on the page

Comment: I can't find those elements on your example page